# How to calculate average and std. dev for all rows matching a criteria?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner to R and trying to learn it by practice (which means I'm not fully aware of the terminology here). My problem is as follows:

I have performed a series of experiments with some benchmarks and collected a few metrics. I already have my data organized as follows:

```
"Benchmark", "Metric", "Value"
```

where `Benchmark` and `Metric` are from a discrete set and `Value` is an integer or float. Each (`Benchmark`, `Metric`) row appears multiple (20) times in the set, reflecting 20 distinct measurements.

What I want to do is transform this data set into the following

```
"Benchmark", "Metric", "Avg. Value", "Std. Dev"
```

which means I want to iterate over all possible (`Benchmark`, `Metric`) pair (without enumerating them all), select all rows matching this pair, compute the avg and `stddev` of the `Value` column and add these to a new table where each (`Benchmark`, `Metric`) pair appears only once.

I am aware of the package `dplyr`. Can I accomplish this using `dplyr`?
(since I am a beginner, any good R tutorial will be useful, too)

Thanks in advance

PS: Example data set

```
"Benchmark","Metric","Value"
BM1,Cycles,712890471
BM1,Cycles,712890472
BM1,Cycles,712890161
BM1,Cycles,712897831
BM1,Cycles,712894735
BM2,Cycles,512390471
BM2,Cycles,542390472
BM2,Cycles,512891261
BM2,Cycles,512896031
BM2,Cycles,512864735
BM1,ExecTime,35.4
BM1,ExecTime,35.6
BM1,ExecTime,32.1
BM1,ExecTime,32.3
BM1,ExecTime,32.3
BM2,ExecTime,51.5
BM2,ExecTime,51.5
BM2,ExecTime,49.6
BM2,ExecTime,49.4
BM2,ExecTime,49.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% group_by(Benchmark, Metric) %>% 
        summarise(value = mean(Value), stdev = sd(Value))
```

Assuming your data is named `dta`, first it is grouped by each benchmark/metric pair (`group_by(Benchmark, Metric)`), then summarised for the mean and sd of ech group (`summarise(value = mean(Value), stdev = sd(Value))`).

For a good general intro to dplyr, see the [data wrangling cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf), or the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

You might also be interest in `data.table`, it's faster than `dplyr`, but a little less intuitive:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)[,list(mean = mean(Value), sd = sd(Value)), by=c("Benchmark", "Metric")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution

```
aggregate(df$Value, b = list(Benchmark = df$Benchmark, Metric = df$Metric), function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x)), simplify = T)

  Benchmark   Metric       x.Mean         x.SD
1       BM1   Cycles 7.128927e+08 3.422044e+03
2       BM2   Cycles 5.186866e+08 1.325260e+07
3       BM1 ExecTime 3.354000e+01 1.792484e+00
4       BM2 ExecTime 5.024000e+01 1.158879e+00
```